# Skipping null values using a for loop

Tags: java, jdbc

[DB_Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtYIB.png)
I'm exploring automation testing on databases and struggling with hitting null values in my table.

I want to test:

1. If EID1 =< 8 and CID1 starts with M, print pass, else, print fail.
2. If EID2 =< 8 and CID2 starts with M, print pass, else, print fail.

There is null values and I'm getting the following error: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because the return value of java.util.Map.get(object) is null.

My first value is always null, so I begin the loop at counter 1, which solved that issue, but there is null values in both EID and CID in my table. It's fine if the test fails if the conditions are not met (ie a value being null), but my application crashes upon reaching any null values. What can I change to avoid crashing and filter null values? I've not been able to work it out. Tried adding the nullpointerexception and some fiddling with the loop but no luck. I have included an example image of the table for reference is required.

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
query = "select * FROM DEA.TUSET where T_DATE >'2010-11-02'";
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(Query)
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
long pId = 1:
while (resultSet.next()) {
for int col = 1; col <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); col ++) {
result.put(rsmd.getColumnLabel(col)+pId, resultSet.getString(col)); }
pId ++;
}
//print all results in col
for (int i=0; i<pId;i++)
System.out.println("EID: "+result.get("EID"+i));

//problem
for (int i=1; i<pId;i++)
if (result.get("EID"+i).startsWith("8"){
if result.get("CID"+i).startsWith("M") {
System.out.println ("true");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before checking the `startsWith()`, check if the value is null or not.

```java
if(result.get("EID"+i)!=null && result.get("CID"+i)!=null ){
    //your code to execute
}
else {
    // some code to execute if the value is null
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, had it all mixed around a bit. Appreciate it!